# How to display data buffer in android?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, buffer

Im new in android develop application.Want to read data from Buffer from my bluetooth socket and display it. the data is from temperature sensor (LM35 > Micro-controller > bluetooth module > android device). below is the coding read and save data to buffer.i want to know,how to display it. hope u guys can help me. thank you very much..

```
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         int bytes;
         try {
              InputStream instream = Bee_btSocket.getInputStream();
              bytes = instream.read(buffer);
             }

         catch (IOException e) {
         break;
```

Comment: Do you have a specification of how data is arranged in such buffer?

Comment: if i try using terminal to display the data, it will show value "36","37" (LM35>MicroC>hyperterminal)..now i want to display it to my adnroid appication..

Answer (score 0):

I do this thing by following code...

```html
public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```